Why my Expo onboardScreen not working correctly
when i open the app after installing it newly first it show the home page and then suddenly change to onBoard screen . When i open the app its not going directly to the onboardscreen.Why is it happening ?
I need to display the onboard screen but its not working correctly.First it show the home screen for a second and then navigate to onboard screen.
Please help if anyone knows.


import FontAwesome from "@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import { Stack, useRouter } from "expo-router";
import * as SplashScreen from "expo-splash-screen";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "react-native-reanimated";
import Providers from "@/redux/provider";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

export {
  ErrorBoundary,
} from "expo-router";

export const unstable_settings = {
  initialRouteName: "/",
};

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function RootLayout() {
  const [loaded, error] = useFonts({
    SpaceMono: require("../assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf"),
    ...FontAwesome.font,
  });

  const [onBoardingChecked, setOnBoardingChecked] = useState(false);
  const [initialRoute, setInitialRoute] = useState("/(onboard)/onboard");
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkOnboardingStatus = async () => {
      try {
        const onBoardSeenData = await AsyncStorage.getItem("inkwellAppData");
        const parsedData =
          onBoardSeenData !== null ? JSON.parse(onBoardSeenData) : null;
        const onboardSeenStatus =
          parsedData !== null ? parsedData?.onboardSeen : null;
        console.log(onboardSeenStatus);

        if (!onboardSeenStatus) {
          console.log("first");
          setInitialRoute("/(onboard)/onboard");
        } else {
          console.log("second");
          setInitialRoute("/");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to load onboarding status:", error);
      } finally {
        setOnBoardingChecked(true);
      }
    };

    checkOnboardingStatus();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) throw error;
  }, [error]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loaded && onBoardingChecked) {
      router.replace(initialRoute);
      SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [loaded, onBoardingChecked, initialRoute]);

  if (!loaded || !onBoardingChecked) {
    return null;
  }
  return <RootLayoutNav />;
}

function RootLayoutNav() {
  return (
    <Providers>
        <Stack screenOptions={{headerShown:false}}>
          <Stack.Screen name="(app)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        </Stack>
    </Providers>
  );
}

